# Wordpress API v2 filter pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, rest

Can anyone answer the following:
I am using postman whilst building an app in React to filter pages. I have a Router setup that should filter the pages and filter them based on the button clicked.

I have tried a few commands

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?filter[orderby]=ID

pages?orderby=asc

/pages?order=desc
```

The result - all pages that are stored in Wordpress. This is frustrating due to the fact that order should be changeable and filtering by id is essential for the follow-up pages.

If anyone can point me to the 'correct' link(s) with working examples I would be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

A new plugin saved the day...
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-filter-fields/

Seems this gives the user more options in the entire filtering of data and thus I use this as solution.

Sorry I couldnt place this answer before.